# strstr() vs Knuth Morris Pratt

Tags: strstr, knuth-morris-pratt

Can someone please help me understanding which one is more efficient strstr() or KMP as recently I was doing a question on SPOJ and found that strstr() was in one way or other faster than KMP..
someone please explain the mystery behind this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing apples with pears, [strstr()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) is a function to find substrings, [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) is an algorithm to do it, so strstr() could theoretically be implemented using KMP. You need to find out which algorithm is the strstr() in question implementing to give a statement.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7587069/1113392) and the comments on it.